# C: Weird conditional printf behavior

Tags: c, printf

```
while(fscanf(f, "%s %s", logIn, pass) == 2){
    i = tabela_insere(logPass, logIn, pass);
    if(i != 0);
    {
        tabela_apaga(logPass);
        printf("%d diferente de 0???\n", i);
        return;
    }
}
```

Pretty straight forward: What is wrong here?

So this cycle only prints anything if the result of that function "tabela_insere()" is different from 0, but as we can see from the printf outcome, i is 0... Why does it print then?

I don't think it matters but here are all variable types used:

```
int i; //not a global variable aka can't be changed in the function
char logIn[26],
     pass[26];
tabela_dispersao *logPass; //it's an hash table
```

I'm using MinGW to compile, no errors or warnings.

Comment: There's a stray semicolon in the code...

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: Also, please don't post pictures of code or text in general. Copy-paste the actual text instead.

Comment: Wow really? that's pretty embarassing... Pretty weird that the compiler doesn't throw a warning about it :/

Comment: Why should the compiler warn about it? The code, as shown, is perfectly legal in all respects of the language. The *logic* on the other hand... :)

Comment: Yes. Your if (i!=0); is causing the problem.
Remove the semicolon and you should be fine.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'll make sure to do that in the future, but mind explaining to me why would that matter?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Why would an if statement with no consequences be used? Seems like a useless thing that the compiler should warn me about, no?

Comment: The syntax of an `if` statement is `if (<expression>) <statement>`. The semicolon on its own is a separate statement, an *empty* statement that doesn't do anything but still a valid statement. The code you show is equal to `if (i != 0) { /* empty */ }`.

Comment: @CarlosPinto I would caution on using non English naming in code.  The problem isn't that people who speak English can't read it, but that *no one else except people who speak your language can*.   If this project isn't public, or is just for personal use it doesn't matter, but notice how you are using both English and Spanish here.   A real use case where this screwed a developer is with [this project](https://github.com/nineties/py-videocore). The lack of English documentation and transperancy of what he was doing lead people to not take claims he made later seriously on QPU capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one semicolon after the if statement that is causing the problem.

```
if (i!=0);
{
     //this will always execute
}
```

change it to

```
if (i!=0)
{
  //this will execute if i != 0
}
```

The compiler does not warn you because the first statement is syntactically valid.